# Converting UTF-8 to WIN1252 using C++Builder 5

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, c++builder-5

I have to import some UTF-8 encoded text-file into my C++Builder 5 program.
Are there any components or code samples to accomplish that?

Comment: ANSI is the American National Standards Institute. So I think you mean ASCII.

Comment: Most likely he means Windows-1252 (also known as WinLatin1), which includes ASCII, but adds another 128 code points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are best off reading all the other questions on SO that are tagged unicode and c++. For starters you should probably look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433301/portable-and-simple-unicode-string-library-for-c-c) and see whether library in the accepted answer ([UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/)) works for you.

I would however first think about what you're trying to achieve, as there is no way you can just import UTF-8-encoded strings into "Ansi" (what ever you mean by that, maybe something like ISO8859_1 or WIN1252 encoding?).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more VCL-centric approach for you:

```
UTF8String utf8 = "...";
WideString utf16;
AnsiString latin1;

int len = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8.c_str(), utf8.Length(), NULL, 0);
utf16.SetLength(len);
::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8.c_str(), utf8.Length(), utf16.c_bstr(), len);

len = ::WideCharToMultiByte(1252, 0, utf16.c_bstr(), utf16.Length(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
latin1.SetLength(len);
::WideCharToMultiByte(1252, 0, utf16.c_bstr(), utf16.Length(), latin1.c_str(), len, NULL, NULL);
```

If you upgrade to CB2009, you can simplify it to this:

```
UTF8String utf8 = "...";
AnsiString<1252> latin1 = utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no-one working on weekends, I have to  answer it myself :)

```
String Utf8ToWinLatin1(char* aData, char* aValue)
{
    int i=0;
    for(int j=0;j<strlen(aData);)
    {   int val=aData[j];
        int c=(unsigned char)aData[j];
        if(c<=127)
        {   aValue[i]=c;
            j+=1;                                  
            i++;
        }
        else if(c>=192 && c<=223)
        {
            aValue[i]=(c-192)*64 + (aData[j+1]-128);
            i++;
            j+=2;
        }
        else if(c>=224 && c<=239)
        {
            aValue[i]=( c-224)*4096 + (aData[j+1]-128)*64 + (aData[j+2]-128);
            i++;
            j+=3;
        }
        else if(c>=240 && c<=247)
        {
            aValue[i]=(c-240)*262144 + (aData[j+1]-128)*4096 + (aData[j+2]-128)*64 + (aData[j+3]-128);
            i++;
            j+=4;
        }
        else if(c>=248 && c<=251)
        {
            aValue[i]=(c-248)*16777216 + (aData[j+1]-128)*262144+ (aData[j+2]-128)*4096 + (aData[j+3]-128)*64 + (aData[j+4]-128);
            i++;
            j+=5;
        }
        else
            j+=1;
    }
    return aValue;
}
```

Comment: You should know that ASCII only has 128 characters compared to the 1,114,112 Unicode characters that can be encoded with UTF-8. So you will loose all characters that are not in the ASCII charset.

Comment: You're function should be better called something like `Utf8ToWinLatin1()` - `ConvertAnsi` doesn't specify what get's converted to what; also, 'ANSI' isn't a name of any encoding...

Comment: I don't care about 1,000,000 characters - I only want my native ones back (ÕÖÄÜ). I called it Ansi, because that's what it is called in Notepad :) when you select SaveAs.

Answer (score -1):

Your question doesn't say specifically which character set you want to convert to. If you only want the basic 7-bit ASCII charset, discarding every character with a higher value than 127 will work.

If you want to convert to a 8-bit character set, such as latin1, you'll have to do it the hard way.

Comment: This way, you'll lose half the characters of WinLatin1 (aka 'ANSI')

Comment: He didn't ask about conversion to Latin1 though, just to "ANSI" which, well, can mean a lot of things. Of course you're right, if he wants to convert to some specific 8-bit character set (such as latin1) then you're right, this won't work.

Comment: @jalf: 'ANSI' is a common, incorrect label for Windows-1252 (aka WinLatin1); check wikipedia for details...

Comment: "The term ANSI as used to signify Windows code pages is a historical reference, but is nowadays a misnomer that continues to persist in the Windows community"

Comment: Yep, not saying that isn't what he meant, just that if it isn't, and if he only wants the 128 ASCII chars, this is a much simpler solution than his own

Comment: In any case there will be data loss then there are characters that are not element of the smaller charset.

Comment: Yes, I don't want any cyrillic or Chinese characters, I just need the common Win-1252 symbols out (like öõäü). And it works.