# Small open source Unicode library for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, unicode

Does anyone know of a great **small** open source Unicode handling library for C or C++? I've looked at [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), but it seems way too big.

I need the library to support:

- all the normal encodings
- normalization
- finding character types - finding if a character should be allowed in identifiers and comments
- validation - recognizing nonsense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I looked at UT8-CPP, and libiconv, and neither seemed to have all the features I needed. So, I guess I'll just use ICU, even though it is really big. I think there are some ways to strip out the unneeded functions and data, so I'll try that. [This page](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu_data/#customizing-icus-data-library) (under "Customizing ICU's Data Library") describes how to cut out some of the data.

Comment: What were the features you needed that were missing? Maybe you should edit the question to say "is there a small Unicode library that does A, B and C without all the overhead of D, E and F?" Then you might find what you are looking for.

Comment: There's a whole section about [Making ICU smaller][smaller] - you can even link to it statically.

  [smaller]: http://userguide.icu-project.org/packaging#TOC-Making-ICU-Smaller

Answer (score 8):

Well, [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) is a good starting point at least.

Also, a google search returns another stackoverflow question! The horror!
[SO: Light C unicode library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313555/light-c-unicode-library)

Answer (score 8):

[UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) was recommended in the accepted answer to a similar question: [Portable and simple unicode string library for C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433301/portable-and-simple-unicode-string-library-for-c-c)

Answer (score 0):

How many features do you really need? In many cases I find converting to one type internally (e.g. UTF8) and handling the various encodings only when loading or saving is more than sufficient. If you are willing to spend a little time and write a class to handle that I'm sure you will reuse it again and again.

I have one lying around somewhere, but iirc the UTF32LE/BE is untested: http://aaq.cc/d

If your project really does need to handle various encodings other than to load/save files then you are probably best off with a library though...

Comment: This link goes elsewhere...Dead link

Answer (score 0):

Also consider the Reichwein Unicode library: https://www.reichwein.it/unicode/

It is a fast, locale independent and header only conversion and validation library.